# Android: How to access the notch Area for displaying app content?

Tags: android, android-fullscreen, android-immersive

I have a phone with a notch.

When I want my activity to go full-screen,

1. the notch area is inaccessible, it becomes black.
2. Navigation bar goes away normally.

I have seen other apps also cannot access the notch area, both sides of notch just become black.

But, Amazon prime video app is able to display on the whole screen, including the area adjacent to the notch.

How Amazon Prime Video app able to do it?